# Is there a JavaEE locking mechanism for two JBoss servers who are both processing a queue?

Tags: jakarta-ee, concurrency, jboss, cluster-computing

I have 2 identical, standalone JBoss 5.1 servers. I am writing an application that wakes up periodically to process a queue, which is implemented as a table in an Oracle database.

The pseudo-code is:

1. Wake up.
2. Is the current time between 7am and 7pm? If yes, continue. If no, go back to sleep for 5 minutes.
3. Read the contents of the first row in the 'queue' table
4. Send a HTTP POST to another server with the content read in step 3.
5. If the POST succeeds, remove the row. Else, leave the row in the table.
6. Move on to the next row and repeat steps 3-5 until the end of the table.
7. Go to sleep for 5 minutes.

My question is: how do I ensure a row is not processed twice (resulting in two POSTs)?

Is there a JavaEE annotation I can take advantage of, or a locking mechanism built-in to JBoss?

The ideal solution will result in an application is deployed to both servers identically; that is, the same application resides in both nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a JMS queue, with multiple consumers.

If configured correctly, each message will be delivered to only one consumer and the JMS provider will "load balance" between the multiple consumers.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't able to use JMS queue (which in this case should be a natural choice), you can use HA Singleton. It works like a cluster wide singleton, where when server with active singleton crash, singleton is activated on a second server.

In your case, singleton bean can separate work between two servers (local and remote), there is no need to use any locks then.

I have used ha-singleton on JBoss 7.1, but this feature is also available for Jboss 5.x ([check here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/WritingAClusteredHASingletonServiceAS5x)).